# VBA gives a negative value when should give a positive

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set the value of the field p_person as 1 when the `bbp.ind=Y`.

```vb
SqlStmt = "UPDATE person " & _
            " SET p_person = 1 " & _
            " FROM Person p INNER JOIN " & PersonTableName &
              " bbp ON p.personID = bbp.personID " & _
            " WHERE bbp.ind = 'Y' " & BBPersonsManual_Filter_and
SqlConn.Execute SqlStmt, RecordsAffected
LogRecords "Update p_person", Str(RecordsAffected)
```

Instead of 1, the value is being defined as -1 when the value of the `bbp.ind=Y`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Boolean column, then 0 will be interpreted as `False` and any value unequal 0 will be treated as `True`. The standard value for `True` is `-1` in an Access table.

So, this behavior is expected. When you test the value of a Boolean column (a Yes/No column) don't test `p_person = 1` or `p_person <> 1`. Instead test `p_person <> 0` or `p_person = 0`. Like this it does not matter whether there is `1` or `-1` in the column.